# How would I reverse the order of these integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

In the question, x is the first integral at the moment. Its $\sin^{-1}(y^2)<x<\pi/2$.
Y is the second integral which needs to become the first. Its $0<y<1$. I know how to integrate the given function => $1/\sqrt{\sin x}$, I'm just not sure how to reverse the order for these values. Thanks.

Edit (by Brian Tung): The actual integral is evidently

$$
\int_{y=0}^1 \left( \int_{x=\sin^{-1} y^2}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \right) \, dy
$$

Comment: It would be clearer if you would write out the actual double integral.  Is it $\int_{y=0}^1 \left( \int_{x=sin^{-1} y^2}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}} \right) \, dy$?

Comment: Yes. Didn't know how to do that @BrianTung

Comment: I've put it in the question.  You can open up the edit window to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change the order of integration in
$$
\int_0^1 \int^{\pi/2}_{\arcsin(y^2)} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{\sin x}}
$$

You are essentially integrating over a "triangle" where the lower edge is the $x$-axis, the right edge is the vertical line $x=\pi/2$ and the third (curvy) side is given by the function $x = \arcsin(y^2)$, which in that interval is equivalent to $y = \sqrt{\sin x}$.

Here is the plot:

[image]

So your modified double integral is
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{\sin x}} \frac{dydx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}
$$